# Want more details on Devata khanda sutra by kasakrtsna

Tags: vedas, vedanta, mimamsa

It is clear that the complete mimansa was supposed to be not comprised of just two mimamsas (purva and uttara) but three mimamsas (add to the list the devata khanda sutras by kasakrtsna), but the devata khanda sutras are said to be lost ... But is that true?..is there no way to know what was it's main argument or thesis ?...because i find knwoing this mimamsa is sort of crucial for clearing many doubts.